# Prevent duplicate records from submitting; PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Good day everyone, I'm trying to prevent duplicate records from being injected into a database of mine, I'm using the following code to prevent the data:

---

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbPos");
$first=trim($_POST['first']);
$last=trim($_POST['last']);
$emailaddress=trim($_POST['emailaddress']);

$queryF = "SELECT firstname FROM tbData WHERE firstname=='$first'";
$queryL = "SELECT lastname FROM tbData WHERE lastname=='$last";
$queryE = "SELECT emailaddress FROM tbData WHERE emailaddress=='$emailaddress'";

$resultF = mysqli_query($queryF);
$resultL = mysqli_query($queryL);
$resultE = mysqli_query($queryE);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($con,$resultF) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($con,$resultL) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($con,$resultE) > 0)
            {
              header("Location: https://www.youtube.com"); //Just to check if it ignores the input.
 }else{
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbData VALUES (
        '$first',
        '$last',
        '$emailaddress')");
header("Location: HOME.php");}
mysqli_close($con);
```

---

So I need it to check the first, and last name and the email address if there's a duplicate of it on the database, before it goes to the part of the code where it injects the data. Unfortunately, the code block where I check if there's a duplicate returns '0', so it proceeds on injecting the code in.

*Basically, the App should ignore the data inputted if it has the same first name, last name, and email address.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming that you are willing to have people with the same name in the database, just not the same email-address? Or, at worst, the same firstname, lastname and emailaddress? The point is, you probably want to check for email first, at least, since that is the only unique value you have.  Also, you need to prepare that query, and stop using outdated methods. Read up on preparing mysqli_ queries, please. Run one query to check for email-address - if it's found, send the user to youtube, if not, allow the insert.

Comment: So if someone has the same first name as another user, they won't be allowed to submit?

Comment: Once you've seen one John, you've seen them all.

Comment: Do you checked  is the `$queryF`,`$queryL`, `$queryE`  returns any data?

Comment: You're giving wrong arguments to `mysqli_num_rows`. It just takes one argument, the result, you shouldn't have `$con` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following logic with code below:

```
$resultFLE = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbData WHERE firstname='$first' AND lastname='$last' AND emailaddress='$emailaddress'");
$countFLE = mysqli_num_rows($resultFLE);
if($countFLE != null ){
     header("Location: HOME.php");
}else{
     mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbData VALUES ( 
         ...
     header("Location: HOME.php");
}
```

I tried to simplified things, and think of it again; tried to locate affected row first by comparing it to the inputted data one by one, counted it just to see if it hits my counter, and then routed the page to wherever I want to based on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing 3 separate queries, since the found values might be in different rows. If someone enters `John Jones`, you would match `John Smith` and `Fred Jones`, so it would think there's a duplicate when there isn't.

You should do a single query for all 3 columns:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbData
WHERE firstname = '$first' AND lastname = '$last' AND emailaddress = '$emailaddress'
```

As mentioned in the comments, you should also learn how to use prepared queries, or at least use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize user input.

You're also calling `mysqli_num_rows()` wrong. It should just be:

```
mysqli_num_rows($result)
```

without the `$con` argument.

Comment: Hi, Barmar! Thanks for trying to submit a solution; however, your suggestion to compile everything on a single query has already been done in this line of code stated above: 

if(mysqli_num_rows($con,$resultF) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($con,$resultL) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($con,$resultE) > 0)

I'm basically checking if the inputted data has a duplicate with the 3 columns.

Comment: No, that's wrong. That's checking whether all the inputs exist, but not if they're the same row.

Comment: Oh God! You're correct! However, can you suggest a method where we could check if its on the same row? I'm thinking adding an auto-increment primary key which will act as the row number, then after checking for the first name, last name, and email address, check if they have the same row number.

Comment: Just add a unique key on the three columns, then it won't let you create duplicates.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE KEY (firstname, lastname, emailaddress)`